# How To Cross Reference Two Big Data Tables With Google BigQuery SQL?

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have two medical data tables that I'm looking to find the hospitals that are common in each table and use two of the fields associated with each hospital in their respective tables. But keep in mind they are in two different tables.

This is what I have so far, but it always comes back with no results.

```
SELECT
  Spending / Rating AS Ratio,
  Provider_ID_Info AS ID
FROM (
  SELECT
    Period,
    Provider_ID_Spend,
    Avg_Spending_Per_Episode_Hospital as Spending,
    Provider_ID_Info,
    Hospital_overall_rating as Rating
  FROM
    [OmniHealth.HospitalSpending],
    [OmniHealth.HospitalGeneralInfo]
  WHERE
    Provider_ID_Info = Provider_ID_Spend  
  GROUP BY
    Rating,
    Spending,
    Provider_ID_Spend,
    Avg_Spending_Per_Episode_Hospital,
    Provider_ID_Info,
    Hospital_overall_rating,
    Period 
    )

  GROUP BY
    Ratio,
    ID,
    Spending,
    Rating

  ORDER BY
    Ratio
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem with your query was in fact that in BigQuery legacy SQL - comma is used as a UNION ALL - not as JOIN!!!

So, try below for BigQuery Legacy SQL (as it is a sql dialect of query in your question )

```sql
#legacySQL
SELECT
  Spending / Rating AS Ratio,
  Provider_ID_Info AS ID
FROM (
  SELECT
    Period,
    Provider_ID_Spend,
    Avg_Spending_Per_Episode_Hospital AS Spending,
    Provider_ID_Info,
    Hospital_overall_rating AS Rating
  FROM
    [OmniHealth.HospitalSpending] s
  JOIN
    [OmniHealth.HospitalGeneralInfo] i
  ON
    i.Provider_ID_Info = s.Provider_ID_Spend  
  GROUP BY
    Rating,
    Spending,
    Provider_ID_Spend,
    Provider_ID_Info,
    Period 
)
GROUP BY
  Ratio,
  ID,
  Spending,
  Rating
ORDER BY
  Ratio
```

It is recommended to work with BigQuery Standard SQL

```sql
#standardSQL
SELECT
  Spending / Rating AS Ratio,
  Provider_ID_Info AS ID
FROM (
  SELECT
    Period,
    Provider_ID_Spend,
    Avg_Spending_Per_Episode_Hospital AS Spending,
    Provider_ID_Info,
    Hospital_overall_rating AS Rating
  FROM
    `OmniHealth.HospitalSpending` s
  JOIN
    `OmniHealth.HospitalGeneralInfo` i
  ON
    i.Provider_ID_Info = s.Provider_ID_Spend  
  GROUP BY
    Rating,
    Spending,
    Provider_ID_Spend,
    Provider_ID_Info,
    Period 
)
GROUP BY
  Ratio,
  ID,
  Spending,
  Rating
ORDER BY
  Ratio
```

Please note: you might be having issues with ambiguous fields if you have any as result of JOIN  - so you will need to use respective aliases - `s` or `i`

Update:
also removed extra columns in GROUP BY

Yet another update for run with real data

```sql
Ratio   ID
   0.0  10019
   9.0  10019
  39.5  10019
  86.0  10019
 236.5  10019
 458.5  10019
 485.0  10019
 531.0  10019
1259.0  10019
1772.0  10019
8834.0  10019
```

It is totally another story if this makes sense or not - but it is your query/logic - so up to you

Comment: Thank you so much! For some reason, I keep getting null in my 'ratio' fields. But then if I replace 'spending' and 'rating' with the specific fields they refer to, I get this error: "Unrecognized name: Avg_Spending_Per_Episode_Hospital at [2:3]"

Comment: definitely, you shouldn't replace fields names or if you want - in this case you need to remove also respective aliases and use original fields. So at least now we resolved your issue with wrong syntax for JOIN. to further address NULL - you should present simplified example of your data for both tables so we will be able to resolve this. make sense?

Comment: Also check [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Its kind of hard to present simplified data, but its not hard to understand. They're just plain CSV. https://storage.googleapis.com/omnihealth/HospitalSpending.csv

Comment: just tested  - works for me - in a sense that i am getting result - see an example of output in update i just did.

Comment: if you still have a problem  - check your real data in bigquery table - not in csv file. potentially you had a problem with loading your data. just trying to speculate on potential directions for you to look into

Comment: @Carson P if you like this answer it would be good to make it the chosen answer by clicking on the checkmark next to the answer.

Comment: Okay so it seems I wasn't clear on my goal. From what it looks like in your data output, all the IDs are the same. My intention is to have each matching ID to have its respective spending and rating evaluated. So the final output will have all the IDs of the hospitals, and there will only be one ratio per ID. Again, I am very thankful for your help!

Comment: UPDATE: I just had the ratio order going the wrong way, so it was showing all the null ones first! Thanks so much!

Comment: that's exactly what I meant by `t is totally another story if this makes sense or not ` - you should revisit/clean your logic and having above example try to end up with working query. if still problems  - ask/post new question and we will be glad to help you!